# What's the best CMS in asp.net mvc? Orchard 1.0 or Kooboo 3 CTP?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, kooboo

I want to build a blog in ASP.NET and I'm choosing among these CMS systems:

- [Orchard CMS 1.0](http://orchard.codeplex.com)
- [Kooboo CMS 3 CTP](http://kooboo.codeplex.com)

Both are based on ASP.NET MVC 3.

Which of these would your vote go to and why? I expect the best Kooboo 3 CTP < familiarity, simplicity and more pro!

- Which will have better support in the future (updates, fixes)?
- Which has a larger community (development, plugins, etc.)?

I'm confused and hesitant much, I very love Wordpress but, I'm a .NET developer and want to use ASP.NET for my blog.

Comment: This is a very subjective question...

Comment: You may also want to look at the licensing. Koodoo is GPL while Orchard's one is more flexible, BSD-style by the looks of it. Potentially this may be a factor as well.

Comment: Kooboo has changed to a Revised BSD license for v4: http://www.kooboo.com/licensefaq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I've not heard of Kooboo, but I have heard of Orchard.

Orchard is being worked on (but not "owned") by Microsoft - that's as good of an endorsement for any product you'll get in the .NET space I think. As far of which'll get better support - I'd have to say that Orchard would because of that alone. I think it'll also get more publicity because of the MS connection too.

However, if you're a .NET developer - then it really comes down to whichever you like the feel of better I guess. If you feel you want to start changing things and getting your hands dirty with the source - then go for the one *you* like.

Other than that, the future will hold the answers, so maybe wait a few months and see how things are looking then :)

Comment: thanks Amadiere, Unfortunately, I decided to use wordpress because it is the best without a rival, I can not find wordpress alternative in asp.net, better and greater support, many plugins.

Comment: I agree. WordPress is the best. The .NET will need to rise a bit further before it becomes a better alternative from a User PoV.

Comment: Isn't word press a blog and not CMS?

Comment: I would look at kooboo cms again, it is one of the best architectured open source cms systems built on .NET and that actually follows the best practices of .net development (mvc, DI, IoC and so on).

Answer (score 1):

I used Kooboo in several projects. I also looked at Orchard. Orchard is good, but Kooboo is really cool CMS on .NET